# What is the best way of handling users session in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net

Any user who logs in needs to provide username, password and domain. For that user a windows identity shall be created on the server side. In this scenario what is the best way to handle user's session across the pages using his identity in ASP.Net?

Comment: Are you asking how to do forms auth with active directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the username, password, domain is authenticated against an Active Directory?  If so, you'll be interested in this article: [How To: Use Forms Authentication with Active Directory in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998360.aspx)

If you are just using session to 'remember someone is logged in' this will handle it all for you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe i don't understand the question here but to me it seems like you could just created a custom membership/profile provider that authenticates to AD.  If the the account can not be found then create them.  this would allow you to act as normal on the asp.net side of things while still allowing you to interact with AD.

MS Howto:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998360.aspx

sorry if this is not what you are looking for, but this seems right based on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use session variable to store user details.

Comment: Can we make a session variable to expire when user clicks on browser button and returns to login page?

Comment: Its better to use a log off button to abandon the session.

Comment: Even after providing log off button if user clicks browser buttons and returns to login page, it is good to abandon the session in that page right?

Comment: I don't think so. Sorry if I am wrong. Usually session ends in two ways. Either the user logs off or session timeout occurs.